# Is there a function in the Go standard library that will encode a buffer to any image format in go

Tags: go

I'm writing a micro-service with some simple image manipulation in go.

When I come to sending the manipulated image back to the user I have to encode it correctly before writing it via a buffer.

I can detect the format easily enough, so it's not precisely a problem. Currently I use my format string and do it like this:

```
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

switch format { //format is just a string as returned by image.Decode()
case "jpeg":
    err := jpeg.Encode(buffer, img, nil) //img is just an image.Image 
    if err != nil {
        //Do some error handling
    }
case "png":
    err := png.Encode(buffer, img)
    if err != nil {
        //Do some error handling
    }
//and so on...
```

Now this works just fine, I was about to split it out into my own function when I started to think I must have missed something here. It seems too obvious to not have a function like `image.Encode(buffer, image, format)`.

It's not exactly hassle to write it, but my code will soon become unnecessarily unwieldy if I start re-implementing core language functionality.

If it's just not there because go is a nice tidy language with a small footprint, I'm cool with that.

Comment: I think the main problem in regards to having an `image.Encode...` method, is that it would cause a circular package reference (I would think, anyway). Best to leave such a small implementation up to consumers I would have thought.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I wouldn't have expected that to be the reasoning, since you could write it in such a way as to not have a circular import pretty trivially (the above being half of one crappy example).

ThunderCat's answer hits the nail on the head I think, given that the encoding functions each have different options that make no sense for other encoding options.

Comment: Makes sense (haven't used the image package or its sub packages to any great extent.. hence why I didn't stupidly answer this question with that comment :P)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library does not contain a function for encoding an image to an arbitrary format.

One reason that the library does not have such a function is that there are different encoding options for each image format. For example the [JPEG options](http://godoc.org/image/jpeg#Options) and [PNG options](http://godoc.org/image/png#Encoder) are different.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.

It's actually pretty fortunate you pointed out the reasoning to me; the next bit of functionality I need to write would use the quality param of the jpeg.Encode, so I would have wasted my effort hiding that away from myself in an abstraction.

Thanks very much!